# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.http.HttpHost#1a451d4d'

Tags: spring

I am using spring version 4.3.12 RELEASE and JAVA 8.
While running my project i am getting  Error creating bean with name `org.apache.http.HttpHost#1a451d4d`

However i added the following dependency in my pom

Apache Http Client

```xml
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.3</version>
```

Still i got the same error below is my fullstack trace

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.bureauveritas.summer.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactoryBasicAuthentication#7fa98a66' defined in class path resource [spring/context-dao.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.apache.http.HttpHost#1a451d4d' of type [org.apache.http.HttpHost] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.http.HttpHost#1a451d4d' defined in class path resource [spring/context-dao.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Could not convert argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [int]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${detention.syncgateway.admin_api.port}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.http.HttpHost#1a451d4d' defined in class path resource [spring/context-dao.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Could not convert argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [int]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${detention.syncgateway.admin_api.port}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 23 more
Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.http.HttpHost#1a451d4d' defined in class path resource [spring/context-dao.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Ambiguous argument values for parameter of type [java.net.InetAddress] - did you specify the correct bean references as arguments?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:736)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
```

========================================context-dao.xml=========================

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task     http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">



    <!-- =========================================================================================================== -->
    <!-- REST -->
    <!-- =========================================================================================================== -->
    <bean id="parentRestTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate"
        abstract="true">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="com.bureauveritas.summer.http.client.ClientHttpRequestLoggingInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter" />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter" />
                <!-- support multipart/related content type -->
                <bean
                    class="com.bureauveritas.detention.dao.impl.MultipartRelatedHttpMessageConverter" />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter" />
                <!-- Use our Jackson object mapper -->
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="jacksonObjectMapper"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean"
        lazy-init="true">
        <property name="featuresToDisable">
            <array>
                <util:constant
                    static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES" />
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="serializers">
            <array>
                <bean
                    class="com.bureauveritas.summer.web.util.json.MessageSourceResolvableJsonSerializer" />
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="syncGatewayAdminRestTemplate" parent="parentRestTemplate">
        <property name="requestFactory">
            <bean
                class="com.bureauveritas.summer.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactoryBasicAuthentication">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.apache.http.HttpHost">
                        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="${detention.syncgateway.admin_api.hostname}" />
                        <constructor-arg index="1" type="int" value="${detention.syncgateway.admin_api.port}" />
                        <constructor-arg index="2" type="java.lang.String" value="${detention.syncgateway.admin_api.scheme}" />
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="connectTimeout" value="10000" />
                <property name="connectionRequestTimeout" value="10000" />
                <property name="readTimeout" value="30000" />
                <property name="user"
                    value="${detention.syncgateway.admin_api.username}" />
                <property name="password"
                    value="${detention.syncgateway.admin_api.password}" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="syncGatewayPublicRestTemplate" parent="parentRestTemplate">
        <property name="requestFactory">

                <bean
                    class="com.bureauveritas.summer.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactoryBasicAuthentication">
                    <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.apache.http.HttpHost">
                        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String"
                            value="${detention.couchbase.api.hostname}" />
                        <constructor-arg index="1" type="int"
                            value="ava.lang.Integer.parseInt('${detention.couchbase.api.port}')" />
                        <constructor-arg index="2" type="java.lang.String"
                            value="${detention.couchbase.api.scheme}" />
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="connectTimeout" value="10000" />
                    <property name="connectionRequestTimeout" value="10000" />
                    <property name="readTimeout" value="30000" />
                </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="couchbaseRestTemplate" parent="parentRestTemplate"
        abstract="true">
        <property name="requestFactory">
            <bean
                class="com.bureauveritas.summer.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactoryBasicAuthentication">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.apache.http.HttpHost">
                        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String"
                            value="${detention.couchbase.api.hostname}" />
                        <constructor-arg index="1" type="int"
                            value="ava.lang.Integer.parseInt('${detention.couchbase.api.port}')" />
                        <constructor-arg index="2" type="java.lang.String"
                            value="${detention.couchbase.api.scheme}" />
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="connectTimeout" value="10000" />
                <property name="connectionRequestTimeout" value="10000" />
                <property name="readTimeout" value="30000" />
                <property name="user" value="${detention.couchbase.api.username}" />
                <property name="password" value="${detention.couchbase.api.password}" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- =========================================================================================================== -->
    <!-- DAOs -->
    <!-- =========================================================================================================== -->
    <bean id="syncGatewayDAO"
        class="com.bureauveritas.detention.dao.impl.DetentionSyncGatewayDAO"
        parent="syncGatewayAdminRestTemplate" />

    <bean id="couchbaseDAO" class="com.bureauveritas.detention.dao.impl.CouchbaseDAO"
        parent="couchbaseRestTemplate" />

    <bean id="detentionChecklistDAO"
        class="com.bureauveritas.detention.dao.impl.DetentionChecklistDAO">
        <constructor-arg ref="syncGatewayDAO" />
        <constructor-arg ref="couchbaseDAO" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: In log there is `spring/context-dao.xml` can you post it?

Comment: Yes i have spring/context-dao.xml i am sharing the same

Comment: Can you add this part of config that shows `detention.syncgateway` ?

Answer (score 0):

In log it is written:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Could not convert argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [int]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${detention.syncgateway.admin_api.port}"

Check what is in `detention.syncgateway.admin_api.port`

Comment: I tried the same but still i am facing the same issue. I also did Interger.parseInt('${detention.syncgateway.admin_api.port}'). error didn't go

Comment: What is the value of `${detention.syncgateway.admin_api.port}` in your property/yaml file?

Comment: In detention.syncgateway.admin_api.port=int, like(12345) took some integer value for it.